# Execute link automatically in php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'd like to execute a link in a automatic way. For example:

I have to pages: Page1.html Page2.php

Page2.php contains a link that has to be clicked to access to the file. What I want to do is that executing Page1.html form, goes to Page2.php and whitout clicking in the link go directly to the link.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a header redirect in Page2.php

```
header('Location: /path-to-your-file.txt');
exit();
```